# Не красавица - уродина

Tags: синонимы

скажите пожалуйста, являются ли слова "не красавица и "уродина" синонимами?

Answer (score 2):

Слова "не красавица и "уродина" не являются синонимами.

Answer (score 1):

Из Ожегова:

А) УРОДИНА -ы, м, и ж. (прост.). То же, что урод (во 2 знач.). Страшная у.

УРОД, 1.  Человек  с физическим  уродством.  У.  от рождения. 2. Человек,  некрасивый  до  безобразия.

Б) НЕ КРАСАВИЦА - человек со средней внешностью.

Соответственно, приведенные слова не являются синонимами ни по значению, ни по стилю.

Comment: "То же, что урод (во 2 знач.). Страшная у. " Интересный расклад: а что,  бывает красивая уродина?